# Mouse selection broken

Tags: mouse, 19.10, hardware, interface

I'm having a strange problem where the left mouse button doesn't work properly when dragging a window, selecting text, etc. It "releases" either immediately or after at most a couple of seconds even if the mouse button is still physically held down. This seems to happen 100% of the time, although the specific amount of time before release changes.

I've looked through quite a few related questions, but they all seem to be about specific programs. Is there any general reason that this would happen? This is a fairly new Ubuntu installation without too many programs installed.

Comment: Could be a few things.  Should also give more specs in your question.  Would clean inside of the mouse and the surface it is used on first.  Change battery if wireless, change USB port if not.  See if another mouse acts the same.  Check settings in Ubuntu under mouse, keyboard, and accessibly.

Comment: 19.10 is out of support now so be a good idea to upgrade/clean install of 20.04.